# Why ifndef is not allowed inside a macro?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write something like this:

```
#define set(x){cout<< x}
int main() {
    set(#ifdef A  1 #else 3 #endif );
    return 0;
}
```

But it does not work, my question is why?
Why doesn't C allow the code to work? what the problem with `ifndef` inside a macro?

Comment: Because the syntax isn't specified that way, simple as that. Why _should_ C allow this strange code to work and what problem would that solve?

Comment: If I want to send the function a parameter depends on the define?
And It does not seem hard to implement it, so why not?

Comment: Why can't you use `#ifdef A #define B 1 #else #define B 3 #endif` ... `set(B);`?

Comment: What does "not allowed" mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @Lundin
I can, just interests why this code does not work, thought that maybe there is some reason(hard to implement, something that refers to the preprocessor, etc), but as you say, maybe it just a matter of syntax

Comment: @nicomp 
Compile error
: stray '#' in program
     set(#ifdef A  1 #else 3 #endif );

Comment: your code is not valid C. And it doesn't compile in C++ either. See also [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who said no?

```
set(
    #ifdef A
        1 
    #else
        3
    #endif
);
```

The above snippet works as expected. [Demo on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3odGx1)

`#` is a special character that starts a preprocessor directive and must be at the start of the line (after optional whitespaces) so you must separate into new lines. Anyway that's not what people usually do, because they'll do like this

```
#ifdef A
    set(1);
#else
    set(3);
#endif
```

or

```
#ifdef A
    #define VAL 1
#else
    #define VAL 3
#endif
set(VAL);
```

Note that **`cout <<` is not C** and you're missing a semicolon in the macro. It should be `{cout<< x;}`